# Multiple independent ST/State monads within a Monad Transformer (RandT)...complicated wrapping/unwrapping

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

Just learning how to get a deeper intuitive grasp of monads and transformers; a lot of things that might seem obvious are still kind of tricky to me haha.

So I have a computation that lives in the `Rand` monad, but *inside* it, there is another "sub-computation" (or multiple) that lives inside an `ST` monad (or `State` monad, for all it matters ... `ST` only for performance but I think `State` works just as well in this context).

The entire computation doesn't need to be inside the `ST` monad...and this sub-computation will be called multiple times with different starting states, so I don't want to coerce the entire thing into an `ST` (unless that's the idiomatic way).

Without randomness, the structure looks like this:

```
main = print mainComp

mainComp :: Int
mainComp = otherComp + (subComp 1) + (subComp 2)

subComp :: Int -> Int
subComp n = runST $ do
  -- generate state based on n
  -- ...
  replicateM_ 100 mutateState
  -- ...
  -- eventually returns an ST s Int

mutateState :: ST s ()
mutateState = -- ...
```

Basically things work pretty well and there is complete referential transparency in `mainComp` and `subComp`.

This is how I've so far used `Rand` --

```
main = (evalRandIO mainComp) >>= print

mainComp :: (RandomGen g) => Rand g Int
mainComp = do
  subResultA <- subComp 1
  subResultB <- subComp 2
  return $ otherComp + subResultA + subResultB

subComp :: (RandomGen g) => Int -> Rand g Int
subComp = return $ runST $ do           -- is this ok to just throw in return?
  -- generate state based on n
  -- ...
  replicateM_ 100 mutateState
  -- ...
  -- eventually returns an ST s Int (??)

mutateState :: ??
mutateState = ??
```

What is the type of `mutateState` supposed to be, if I wanted to use the random seed and the `Rand` monad in it?  I think I might want to use a return type of `RandT g (ST s) ()`, but how do I make that fit in with the type expected in the `runST` in `subComp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With monad transformers, you 'peel off' layers in the inverse order in which you add them. So, if you have something of type `RandT g (ST s) ()`, you start by eliminating the RandT using `evalRandT` or `runRandT`, and only then calling `runST`.

Here's a simple example of combining `RandT` and `ST`:

```
import Data.STRef
import System.Random

import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.ST
import Control.Monad.Random
import Control.Monad.Random.Class

stNrand :: RandT StdGen (ST s) Int
stNrand = do
    ref <- lift $ newSTRef 0
    i <- getRandomR (0,10)
    lift $ writeSTRef ref i
    lift $ readSTRef ref

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn . show $ runST $ evalRandT stNrand (mkStdGen 77)
```

**Edit:** Here's an expanded version, now with a function `runSTBelowRand` that lets you embed `RandT StdGen (ST s) a` computations in `Rand StdGen a` computations. The function uses [getSplit](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/MonadRandom/0.1.6/doc/html/Control-Monad-Random-Class.html#v%3agetSplit) to split the seed of the global computation, and feed the new seed to the sub-computation.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Data.STRef
import System.Random

import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.ST
import Control.Monad.Random
import Control.Monad.Random.Class

stNrand :: RandT StdGen (ST s) Int
stNrand = do
    ref <- lift $ newSTRef 0
    i <- getRandomR (0,10)
    lift $ writeSTRef ref i
    lift $ readSTRef ref

runSTBelowRand :: (forall s. RandT StdGen (ST s) a) -> Rand StdGen a
runSTBelowRand r = do
    splittedSeed <- getSplit
    return $ runST $ evalRandT r splittedSeed

globalRand :: Rand StdGen (Int,Int)
globalRand = do
    i1 <- runSTBelowRand stNrand
    -- possibly non-ST stuff here
    i2 <- runSTBelowRand stNrand
    return (i1,i2)

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn . show $ evalRand globalRand (mkStdGen 77)
```

Comment: The thing is, I might have multiple `runST`'s within one computation -- or most of my computation is done without the state and only some parts of it are within a state.  How would I tweak this so that my computatation can launch multiple, independent, different `runST`'s?

Comment: I modified my question to reflect the first requirement mentioned

Comment: If RandT were an instance of [MFunctor](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mmorph/1.0.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-Morph.html#t:MFunctor) that would be easy because we could use [hoist](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mmorph/1.0.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-Morph.html#v:hoist) in combination with `runST` to turn a `RandT StdGen (ST s) Int` sub-computation into a `Rand StdGen Int` immediately usable in the wider computation. But the instance doesn't exist and I can't figure how to declare one because the `RandT` constructor isn't exported by `Control.Monad.Random`. This is vexing.

Comment: I have expanded my answer with a workaround. Now you can embed multiple ST computations without problems.

Comment: Yeah, I think it works :)  Thanks :)  I'll probably be using it for now.  However I am a little bugged by the awkward "pseudo-bind" where you use `evalRandT` on a smaller `RandT` even though you're already in a `RandT` monad.  Isn't the whole "purpose" of monads that you don't have to deal with passing seeds like this, or abstracting away this explicit `join`?

Comment: If the data constructor `RandT` were public, a less awkward solution could be possible which wouldn't require splitting the seed.

Comment: If I rename `runSTBelowRand` as `liftST` and hide the implementation in a separate package, things don't look that bad at all :)  I'm going to accept the answer because this with this abstraction I think the overall effect fits the use case pretty well; thank you for all your help!